# Using Service Account to access Google Analytics API doesn't work

Tags: php, google-analytics

I'm trying to access my Google Analytics data using a service account. I've created one in the Developers Console and I've enabled the Google Analytics API in that same console, but somehow, I can't manage to pull data from the API.

I've used the script on [this page](http://www.jasonbailey.net/stuff/connecting-to-google-analytics-brighton-php-october-2013/).

My code is as follows:

```
<?php

$keyfile = 'google/key.p12';
// Initialise the Google Client object
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('MyNAME');
$client->setAssertionCredentials(
        new Google_AssertionCredentials(
        'XXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com', array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'), file_get_contents($keyfile)
        )
);
$client->setClientId('XXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setAccessType('offline_access');
$analytics = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);

$analytics_id = 'ga:UA-XXXXXX-1'; // http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/dRuAr1K4waI
// get data for the last 2 weeks
$lastWeek = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 week'));
$today = date('Y-m-d');
// Test connection
try {
    $results = $analytics->data_ga->get($analytics_id, $lastWeek, $today, 'ga:visits');
    echo '<b>Number of visits this week:</b> ';
    echo $results['totalsForAllResults']['ga:visits'];
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'There was an error : - ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

*Note: if it says "XXXX", that means I've removed part of the string for security purposes; the proper strings are in my actual script.*

It should either display the number of users or a error, but I just get a blank screen. I'm sure the URL to the keyfile is correct.

Does anybody have suggestions on how to fix this? That would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using your property Id (UA-XXXXX-1) in place of your view (profile) id. If you go to [Google Analytics Query Explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/) it makes it easy to see what your actual ga:XXXX view (profile) id is. Any given property can have multiple view's (profiles). [This reference guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#ids) gives a good description of the parameters that this request requires.